# How to insert a date in the format dd-mm-yy in MySQL?

Tags: date, datepicker, date-format

I have to insert dates in MySQL with the format `dd-mm-yy`.

I know that if I change the date format to `yy-mm-dd` it will work, but my client wants it in the format `dd-mm-yy`, and the default format of a MySQL date is `0000-00-00`.

Comment: You can use str_to_date to convert a date string to MySQL's internal date format for inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Honeyboy said in the comments, you can use the [`SELECT_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function with the format string `"%d-%m-%y"`. You can test it like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE TEST;
CREATE TABLE test (date1 date);
INSERT INTO test (date1) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE("03-04-15","%d-%m-%y"));
```

then with

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

you obtain:

```
+------------+
| date1      |
+------------+
| 2015-04-03 |
+------------+
```

If you use PHP, you can then make a prepared statement such as:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (date1) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d-%m-%y'));");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $client_date);
$stmt->execute();
```

Same principle with other languages.

Comment: yes, no problem with that, but the user is inserting the date in the format "dd-mm-yy",

Comment: So you can do an INSERT from the user provided string and the SELECT_TO_DATE function.

Comment: the problem is that when the user insert the date in the form `dd-mm-yy` the value in the database will be `0000-00-00` this means the inserted date must be in this form `0000-00-00` i am confused if i can get the value from the user and transform it to this `yyyy-mm-dd' form before inserting, is there a way?

Comment: Also: sometimes we need to use `now()` to register some event. This way, mySQL will save yyyy-mm-dd. How to workaround this?